# TYPO3: export list of pages with info about last editor

Tags: typo3

I need to create an export of all pages and get information about the last modification date and who did the last modification.

Last modification date is easy: that's stored in `SYS_LASTCHANGED` in the `pages` table. But how can I find the information about who did the change? For changes to `pages` that's easy as well, as I can check `sys_log` and `sys_history` and search the pid in the field `recuid` in combination with `tablename`. For `tt_content` records I can do a select first to get all records for a specific page. And then search `recuid` and `tablename` accordingly.

But how about all the other records, e.g. from plugins? Do I really need to iterate over all tables and the pid field to get all possible records?

Comment: Hi @peter Did you find a solution for your problem. We are looking for a solution, that displays the last update of a page and struggled with `SYS_LASTCHANGED` what does not work (as @bernd-wilke-πφ already answered). Our [current solution is simply done by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085784/get-the-timestamp-of-last-modification-of-typo3-page-difference-between-tstamp) but we are looking for a way to get this done by TypoScript or Fluid.

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of work to do, as the information `SYS_LASTCHANGED` is not very trustworthy.

Depending on the rendering process multiple records are used for building up a page. and more and more information does not come from records but from files, which are versioned by chance in a git repository (or similar).

Just in case all(!) information is stored in records (tsconfig, typoscript, fluid templates in records (sys_file for files)). There are thousands of ways a page is generated and which information influences the current page rendering.

just some examples:

- the typoscript is changed. does it result in a rendering change of the current page?
- a record (e.g. tt_content) is deleted. so this record will **no longer** show in the page. will you consider all invisible (delted, hidden, time restricted) records?
- TYPO3 has constructions like: show content from page X, show content records X,Y,Z from other pages
- translations: does a change in another language than the current is a change to the current language (a fallback might be possible)
- if you consider links in menus or text: if another page which is linked in the current page gets disabled TYPO3 does not generate a link any longer

Comment: Thank you very much for all your considerations. Maybe I was a little bit unclear about my goal. I have csv file with a list of pages for which I need to know whom from the editors has last changed content. In my case thats 95% tt_content and maybe a couple of more records. TypoScript and translation fallback does not apply in my case.